# Azure Data Factory - Error creating a parameterised mapping dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am having an error when trying to create a parameterised Mapping Data Flow. More specifically, I have the following error. Anyone have suggestions on how to fix it or what the error may be?

```
{ "Message": "ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'body('DataFlowDebugExpressionResolver')?.Data Vault Loadb734571b6d5a414ea8387a08077f1ff1?.DataVaultSource.sourcetable': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'Identifier'." } - RunId: 24ee9884-610d-4061-a9be-670aeb8f1660
```

Thanks @Leon and @Joel for your responses. I am attaching my pipelines here for your consideration

[[image: Data Source connection with Parameter. I can preview data with no errors][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRx31.png)

[image: Error caused in the data flow when trying to debug or run the mapping data for (Runtime Error)]

Comment: can you show us the the parameter expression?

Comment: What is the Data Flow parameter type? Pipelines do not support the same variable types, I believe I've seen this before when passing mismatched parameter types.

Answer (score 14):

I have found the resolution to the problem I raised yesterday. The error was caused by the name of the Mapping Data Flow (Data Vault Load).

I raised a request from Microsoft and they had the following suggestion

> Spaces in name of object and parameters does not go well

Once I removed the spaces in my Mapping Data Flow name it, this particular error was resolved.

[image: Fixed Error by removing spaces in the name]

Thanks to everyone that responded.

Comment: Worked for me. Indeed I removed the space from the name of my 'Data Flow'

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a parameterized data set to remove the space from the dataflow name, like this from "dataflow test"

[image]

to "dataflowtest"

[image]

Because when you make use of the parameterized dataset, it shows up in the Settings tab, not in the Parameter tab correctly. I mean, it is just my theory, but it takes its own name according to the dataflow name rule, which is this:

[image]

So when you remove the spaces from your dataflow name, it will work—trust me, because its works for me. As you can see in the below image, I have a lot of parameterized data sets and it's a live project:

[image]

I was getting this error, which was absurd:

[image]

After removing the space, though, we are getting our data:

[image]

So there is no need to create a separate data flow from scratch; if you create the dataflow from scratch you will face the same issue which, will be this space one.

Comment: `enter image description here` is a *placeholder* you are supposed to replace with an actual description.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for going around looking for this answer it is 2021 and Microsoft still didn't add any validation or restriction for the naming of the Data Flow